# my .className variable has a null because it calls from an array at a later time. Cant figure out a work around

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I have this code currently:

```
load = function () {

    var hexArray = ["hexa", "hexb", "hexc", "hexd", "hexe", "hexf", "hexg", "hexh", "hexi", "hexj", "hexk", "hexl", "hexm"];
    var delayArray = ["delaya", "delayb", "delayc", "delayd", "delaye", "delayf", "delayg", "delayh", "delayi", "delayj", "delayk", "delayl", "delaym", "delaya", "delayb", "delayc", "delayd", "delaye", "delayf", "delayg", "delayh", "delayi", "delayj", "delayk", "delayl", "delaym"];
    var divHexArray = ["aa", "ab", "ac", "ad", "ae", "af", "ag", "ah", "ai", "aj", "ak", "al", "am", "an", "ao", "ap", "aq", "ar", "as", "at", "au", "av", "aw", "ax", "ay", "az", "ba", "bb", "bc", "bd", "be", "bf", "bg", "bh", "bi", "bj", "bk", "bl", "bm", "bn", "bo", "bp", "bq", "br", "bs", "bt", "bu", "bv", "bw", "bx", "by", "bz", "ca", "cb", "cc", "cd", "ce", "cf", "cg", "ch", "ci", "cj", "ck", "cl", "cm", "cn", "co", "cp", "cq", "cr", "cs", "ct", "cu", "cv", "cw", "cx", "cy", "cz", "da", "db", "dc", "dd", "de", "df", "dg", "dh", "di", "dj", "dk", "dl", "dm", "dn", "do"];
    var pos = 0;

    function zip(a, b, f) {
        for(var i=0; i < hexArray.length; i++){
            f(a[i], b[i]);
        };
    }

    function phase(a, b, f) {
        for(var i=0; i < divHexArray.length; i++){
            f(a[i], b[Math.floor(Math.random()*26)]);
        };
    }

    wave = function(){
        if(pos < hexArray.length){
            document.getElementById(hexArray[pos]).className='wave';
            pos += 1;
        } else if (pos === hexArray.length) {
            document.getElementById(hexArray[pos]).className='wave';
        } else {
            false;
        }
    };

    for(var i = 0; i < hexArray.length; i++) { 
        document.getElementById(hexArray[i]).addEventListener('animationend', wave, false);
        document.getElementById(hexArray[i]).addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', wave, false);
    };

    zip(hexArray, delayArray, function(x, y) { 
        document.getElementById(x).className = 'transtart burn ' + y;
    });

}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', load, false);
```

It works just fine. I and setting up a secondary function called phase() which you can see. phase() works in the same fashion as zip() does, however I do not want to call phase() on page load like I do with zip(), so Im trying to create a variable that calls phase at a different time.

This is the variable Im trying to add:

```
    var phaseStart = phase(divHexArray, delayArray, function(x, y) { 
        document.getElementById(x).className = 'wave ' + y;
    });
```

The problem I assume Im running into my .className null error, is because of 'y' is a variable without a value. Mostly because while delayArray is named as the variable for y, delayArray doesnt yet have a value because for loop function hasnt been passed through yet to define values for delayArray in that instance. This isnt a problem with zip() because as soon as it is called on page load, the function to define the values runs immediately.

Ive tried a few if/else statements as work arounds, but nothing is seeming to work how I want it to. I am also trying to keep my script from ballooning. If anyone knows a work around I would be very grateful.

Comment: You can defer a function's execution by wrapping it with a `setTimeout` call with 0 delay.

Comment: Did you run phaseStart from outside of the load() function? If so it can't see divHEXArray and delayArray because they are scoped to load function. Try to move them outside load function (just before it should do the trick).

Comment: @Alexey Ivanov nope I havent even tried to call the variable at all yet. So the fact that the variable exists but is not called and is breaking my script tells me that theres something wrong with the variable itself.

Comment: Can you make jsfiddle with the full script that is not working? (And you are calling function by assigning it to variable by the way)

Comment: @Alexey Ivanov Heres my entire HTML document: http://jsfiddle.net/fuPz7/ . I changed the code to reflect what Im trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Answer based on jsfiddle.

```
var phaseStart = phase(divHexArray, delayArray, function(x, y) { 
    document.getElementById(x).className = 'wave ' + y;
});
```

This code not caches function, but tries to execute it and apply `return` value (or `undefined` if there is no `return` in the function) to the `phaseStart`. If you want function with cached arguments to use later you need to return function to variable. For example like this:

```
var phaseStart = function() {
    phase(divHexArray, delayArray, function(x, y) {  
        document.getElementById(x).className = 'wave ' + y;
    });
}
```

This way function will be created, but only accessible from inside `load` function. If you want to see it from outside you will need to define `phaseStart` variable outside of the `load` function. For example like this:

```
var phaseStart;

load = function() {
    ...
    phaseStart = function() {
        ...
    }
    ...
};
```

This way it will be visible from outside. And you will be able to call it with `phaseStart();`. But only after page loading completion, because it is defined inside `load` function.

**Fixed:** Removed unnecessary function wrapper. Now loop works all the way till "ci" element in array before breaking (there is no element with id="ci"). If you remove "ci" form array it works all the way to the end without errors.